# How to tell NEON instructions from VFP instructions?

Tags: neon

As both NEON and VFP instructions are prefixed with v, like `vpush/vpop`, is there a simple way to tell NEON instructions from VFP?

Comment: [Here's the list](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.dui0489i/CJABFHEJ.html).  Note that some of the operations moving data in and out of the register file, including `vpush` and `vpop` are defined as shared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VFP instructions are scalar operations, so if the instruction has the `.f32` suffix and operates on `s` registers, it's VFP.  If it operates on `d` or `q` registers, it's NEON.

If the instruction has the `.f64` suffix, it's a VFP instruction (there are no f64 instructions in 32-bit NEON).

If the instruction has an integer suffix (like `.i8` or `.s32` or `.u16`), it's NEON; VFP doesn't have integer instructions[*]

`*` I'm glossing over scalar conversion instructions slightly.  You can read about the details in the ARM reference manual.